# Why is Actions on Google not calling my OAuth service

Tags: oauth-2.0, actions-on-google

I have written an OAuth 2 code & token service and configured my Actions on Google app with Account Linking. I'm trying to implement the [Streamlined Identity Flow](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-assertion-flow) but when I request the SIGN_IN intent, I don't see any activity in my logs.

When I try to test my auth endpoints from Google's [OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) I do see activity in the logs, so I know I'm doing something right. If I configure the gactions app to use "Google Sign In", the app moves forward, so I've got the code in my app working also.

I've tried "OAuth" and "OAuth & Google Sign In".

I've created and provided a Client ID and secret.

I provide my "[/auth-code](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow#handle_user_sign-in)" in "Authentication URL" and my "[/auth-token](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow#handle_token_exchange_requests)" in "Token URL"

I've also tried testing using the [gala-demo](https://gala-demo.appspot.com/) but it says "Invalid response" (but no activity in my logs).

Comment: Hey there. Just to clarify, are you trying this on a mobile-device surface, or on a speaker-only surface? The SIGN_IN intent only works on screen devices.

Comment: I was hoping to run it on a speaker and see how it hands off to the mobile app. I can't even get it working on a mobile yet though. They're not expecting a browser UI for the streamlined flow with URL are they?  I don't understand why I don't see any logs on my /auth/code endpoint. Do I need to whitelist the URL somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation doesn't make it very clear, but the `auth/code` endpoint is not used at all by the Streamlined identity flow.  It calls directly to the `auth/token` endpoint with the JWT assertion.

The Authentication URL that you provide in the Account Linking page is the fall-back web UI that the user is redirected to if the token endpoint replies with 401 `{"error": "linking_error"}`